# What is the right way to implement a screen showing details from a list in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, react-navigation

So I am working on my first project in React native, which is based on the following mockup: https://ibb.co/PZJ43vz/.
I use a drawer navigation for the 'Assets' and 'Bookings'. In each one of these screens I have a searchable list of assets and bookings. And I wan't to be able to click in a button for 'Show details' at each one of the Assets and Bookings, which will open a new screen for that, and it should be possible to click in a button to return to the list. But I am not sure how I should implement it

Comment: Drawer navigation doesn't run on the same component as another component tree. which makes it hard to navigate back and forth. Can you use Stack Navigation?

Comment: I could, it is not that important to use Drawer.

Comment: Commonly done with Stack Navigator - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/